# Lua and loose Patterns

Tags: lua, design-patterns

In Lua, how would one match 123, against a string that is 11122333, and find the 1 and 2 and 3? is there a pattern that can do this? rather than attaching individual character checks?

Comment: Are you asking about ignoring duplicates or about finding 123 sequence inside a larger sequence of any other characters (for example in `a1b2c3d`?)

Answer (score 2):

```
local str = '11122333'
str = str:gsub('.','\0%0%0'):gsub('(.)%z%1',''):gsub('%z.','')
```